# How to disable same barcode for different producer codes

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, postgresql-9.1, unique-constraint

Postgres 9.1.2 database contains product table

```
create table product (
ProductCode char(10) primary key,
ProducerCode char(15),
BarCode char(13) );
```

how to allow same barcode only for same producer codes.
For example those values are valid:

```
INSERT INto product values ('product1', '1', '1111111111111');
INSERT INto product values ('product2', '1', '1111111111111');
```

but this insert should cause error since barcode 1111111111111 is already used in producer code 1

```
INSERT INto product values ('product3', '2', '1111111111111');
```

Using

"PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit"

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong data structure.  You should have two tables:

```
create table product (
    ProductCode char(10) primary key,
    BarCode char(13)
);

create table BarCode (
    BarCode char(13) primary key,
    ProducerCode char(15)
);
```

This structure will automatically guarantee that a bar code has at most one `ProducerCode`.

Note:  I advise against using strings as primary keys, preferring `serial` columns instead.  `char()` is particularly strange, unless you know for certain that the length of the column is fixed.

EDIT:

Alternatively:

```
create table product (
    ProductCode char(10) primary key,
    ProducerCode char(15)
);

create table ProducerCodes (
    ProducerCode char(15) primary key,
    BarCode char(13) primary key unique
);
```

This should also do what you want.  Note that `BarCode` could be `NULL`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannoy chage database stucture. How to implement this using table structure in question ?

Comment: Answer assumes that barcode is always present. This is wrong. BarCode may be null and only ProducerCode may be specified.

Comment: The answer doesn't appear to make that assumption - if a bar code is null then there will be no row in table BarCode. if there is a BarCode then it will be enforced to belong to one and only one producer.

Comment: Updated answer assumes that ProducerCode is not null. ProducerCode can be also null. How to use this answer if both BarCode and ProducerCode may be nulls ?

Answer (score 0):

Insert into `barcode` a left padded string using `ProducerCode` instead of an entered "Barcode"

Code would look like

```
INSERT INTO Product ( ProductCode , ProducerCode , BarCode ) 
VALUES ('product1' , '1' , LPAD('1' , 13 , '0'))
```

Would result in a unique `Barcode` for each `ProducerCode`

End data would looks like this

```
('product1' , '1' , '0000000000001');
('product2' , '1' , '0000000000001');
('product3' , '2' , '0000000000002');
```

Note the repeated `Barcode` for the corresponding `ProducerCode` in lines 1 and 2

Comment: Is this barcode for the producer or for the product? I misspoke earlier about the uniqueness.

Comment: I dont understand your answer. Can you provide sample code which implements this using data from answer ?

Comment: Sure give me a second.

Comment: No. Barcode is assigned in shop and is same for same producer code.

Comment: `INSERT INto product values ('product3', '2', '1111111111111');`  command should thow error. How to implement this? Also, barcode value shoud be `1111111111111`, not as in your answer

Comment: Is there a reason the bar codes have to remain the same? Presumably you're just printing them off. I've updated the statement to use `VALUES` instead of `SELECT`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176358/discussion-between-edward-and-andrus).

Comment: Yes, barcodes have to remain the same. After scanning barcode menu appears which allows to select product on sale.

Answer (score 0):

if you can not change the database structure, change the insert command

```
INSERT INTO product select 'product3', '2', '1111111111111' where '1111111111111' not in (select barcode from product) returning *
```

then check what was returned to determine if the insert was successful or not

Answer (score 0):

**If you can create functions and triggers** do it in an `ON BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION error_on_barcode_at_another_producer()  RETURNS trigger
    VOLATILE
AS $body$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM products p 
            WHERE p.bar_code = NEW.bar_code AND p.producer_code <> NEW.producer_code) THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'bar_code is already linked to another producer_code';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER tr_error_on_barcode_at_another_producer
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE error_on_barcode_at_another_producer()
```

---

**On the other hand**, it seems that you have no chance for any changes on the schema. Then you have to change your `INSERT` statement. This one has a look into the `products` table if there is the `bar_code` to insert which is already applied to another `producer_code`. If there a match for that condition the `b.*` is not `NULL` and so it will be filtered by the `WHERE` clause. If there is not such case the `SELECT` gets a result which can be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO products

SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM
    (SELECT 'product3' AS product_code, '2' AS producer_code, '1111111111111' AS bar_code) a --your values here
LEFT JOIN products b
ON a.bar_code = b.bar_code AND a.producer_code <> b.producer_code
WHERE b.product_code IS NULL

RETURNING *
```

The `RETURNING` can give you an indication if there was a conflict (no row returned) or not (the inserted row returned)